# Test is not throwing error when expect is inside a loop

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm trying to refactor some of my unit testing but I found out that expect inside a loop doesn't work. I'm looping through enums. I have the following code:

Any solution or workaround for this?

```
it('should block approval of ads if status is not in pending revision', async () => {
  mockAdsRepository.findOne = jest.fn(() =>
    Promise.resolve({ ...adsDto, status: Status.REJECTED }),
  );
  await expect(service.approve(1, 1)).rejects.toThrow(BadRequestException);

  mockAdsRepository.findOne = jest.fn(() =>
    Promise.resolve({ ...adsDto, status: Status.UNPUBLISH }),
  );
  await expect(service.approve(1, 1)).rejects.toThrow(BadRequestException);

  // error trigger, working
  // mockAdsRepository.findOne = jest.fn(() =>
  //   Promise.resolve({ ...adsDto, status: Status.PENDING_REVISION }),
  // );
  // await expect(service.approve(1, 1)).rejects.toThrow(BadRequestException);

  //refactor
  Object.keys(Status).map(async (key) => {
    if (Status[key] !== Status./*changing this value for error triggers not working*/ ) {
      mockAdsRepository.findOne = jest.fn(() =>
        Promise.resolve({ ...adsDto, status: Status[key] }),
      );

      await expect(service.approve(1, 1)).rejects.toThrow(
        BadRequestException,
      );
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: The promise doesn't resolve/reject during the test lifetime. This isn't really a Jest problem, you need to think about the basic control flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, issue in your case is that map doesn't handle async operations, so you have several promises in pending status in the end of your loop. You should await for all promises from map to be resolved / rejected.

You can use this function to handle all promises.

```js
export async function mapAsync<T, R>(
  elements: Promise<T>[] | T[],
  mapAction: (arg: T) => Promise<R>,
): Promise<R[]> {
  const results: R[] = [];
  for (const element of await Promise.all(elements)) {
    const mappedItem = await mapAction(element);
    results.push(mappedItem);
  }
  return results;
}
```

`await mapAsync(Object.keys(Status), async key => {... // your map function with await});`